# Json array into list of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having this json

```
[{'id': '16166cf3', 'quote': 'a.'}, {'id': '16166cfb', 'quote': 'b.'} ]
```

And this Class

```
class Quotes:
    def __init__(self, id, quote):
        self.id = id
        self.quote = quote
```

How can I transform the json arrayList into a list of Quotes??

For now I have this

```
with open("../json/quotes.json") as json_file:
            quote_list = json.load(json_file)
            print(quote_list)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the parsed list, and for each dict in the list, construct an instance of `Quote` with the fields from the dict. You can then append these instances to a new list.

```
with open("../json/quotes.json") as json_file:
    quote_list = json.load(json_file)
    print(quote_list)

instances = []

for q in quote_list:
    instances.append(Quotes(q["id"], q["quote"]))
```

More compact form using list comprehension, and assigning to the same variable:

```
with open("../json/quotes.json") as json_file:
    quote_list = json.load(json_file)
    print(quote_list)
    quote_list = [Quotes(q["id"], q["quote"]) for q in quote_list]
```

Comment: thanks, there's nothing more functional to transform from A to B?